# Concatenate fields using XML and XSLT for-each statement

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I've been working on this file and what I'm trying to do is list all @FlightNumberPublic in one element (separated by a Line Feed character `&#10;`). Now I also need to make sure that all @FlightNumberPublic are the same format, which is what is done by the "formatFlightNumber" template. Now this all works, only I can't seem to figure out how I show all @FlightNumberPublic (instead of only the last one that comes through the for-each statement).

My XML is like this (simplified):

```
<GeneralXMLExportModel xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Flights>
    <Flight>
        <CodeSharings>
            <CodeSharing FlightNumber="KLM122" FlightNumberIATA="KL122" FlightNumberPublic="KL122">
                <Airline Name="KLM" ICAO="KLM" IATA="KL" />
            </CodeSharing>
            <CodeSharing FlightNumber="DLH422" FlightNumberIATA="DL422" FlightNumberPublic="DL422">
                <Airline Name="DLH" ICAO="DLH" IATA="DL" />
            </CodeSharing>                
        </CodeSharings>
    </Flight>
</Flights>
</GeneralXMLExportModel>
```

And my XSL is like this (also simplified):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/"> 
<Arrivals>
    <xsl:for-each select="GeneralXMLExportModel/Flights/Flight">
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;&#x9;</xsl:text>
        <Arrival>
        <xsl:for-each select="CodeSharings/CodeSharing">
            <xsl:attribute name="Codesharing"><xsl:call-template name="formatFlightNumber"><xsl:with-param name="unformattedFlightNumber"  select="@FlightNumberPublic" /></xsl:call-template></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:for-each>   
        </Arrival>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;&#x9;</xsl:text>
</Arrivals>            
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="formatFlightNumber"> 
<xsl:param name="unformattedFlightNumber" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$unformattedFlightNumber = ''" >
            <!-- Prevent this routine from hanging -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$unformattedFlightNumber" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($unformattedFlightNumber, '-')">
            <xsl:variable name="prefix"> <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($unformattedFlightNumber,'-')" /> </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="number"> <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($unformattedFlightNumber,'-')" /> </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, $number)" /> 
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$unformattedFlightNumber" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then the output is like this:

```
<Arrivals>
<Arrival Codesharing="DL422" />
</Arrivals>
```

Now what I'm hoping to achieve is the following:

```
<Arrivals>
<Arrival Codesharing="KL122&#10;DL422" />
</Arrivals>
```

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you do simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/GeneralXMLExportModel"> 
    <Arrivals>
        <xsl:for-each select="Flights/Flight">
            <Arrival>
                <xsl:attribute name="Codesharing">
                    <xsl:for-each select="CodeSharings/CodeSharing">
                        <xsl:value-of select="translate(@FlightNumberPublic, '-', '')" />
                        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:attribute>    
            </Arrival>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Arrivals>            
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yep, that does the trick and is way more easy than what I came up with. Thank you so much for your help!